# QSqlQuery throws exception in dll module

Tags: c++, qt, qtsql

I have 3 different projects in my solution as

- Interops (LIB)
- XModule(DLL, includes a QWidget) {using Interops}
- Main App (EXE) {using Interops, XModule}

I created an logger class in the Interops project as "LogManager" and it connects to MySQL to periodically writing logs to database.

Using the "LogManager" class in "Main App" okay but in XModule (which also used in "Main App") throwing weird exceptions during `QSqlQuery` execution and it isn't debugable. I think that dynamically linked DLL failing to load SQL drivers of Qt but I dont know how to fix.

BTW all projects using SQL Qt module. Thanx.

---

Two Example Functions: wich succeed in MainApp but not in XModule. Throws at `QString val = q.value(0).toString();` line in `getLastDbLogDate()` function. Also I pass pointer of LogManager instance everywhere which instanced in MainApp.

```
bool LogManager::connect()
{
    if(!QSqlDatabase::contains(LOG_DB_NAME))
    {
        QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(mDriver, LOG_DB_NAME);
        if(!db.isValid())
            return false;

        db.setHostName(mHost);
        db.setPort(mPort);
        db.setDatabaseName(mDb);
        db.setUserName(mUser);
        db.setPassword(mPw);

        return db.open();
    }

    return true;
}

QDateTime LogManager::getLastDbLogDate()
{
    if(!connect())
        QDateTime();

    QSqlQuery q("SELECT MAX(logTime) FROM tbl_logs", QSqlDatabase::database(LOG_DB_NAME));
    while (q.next())
    {
        QString val = q.value(0).toString();
        return QDateTime::fromString(val, LOG_DATE_SQL_FORMAT);
    }

    return QDateTime();
}
```

calling like everywhere :

```
mLogMgr->getLastDbLogDate();
```

Comment: Try to create as small example as possible, which shows this problem. And show us your code (not current code! only minimal peace of code for demonstartion of that exception).

Comment: Thanks for comment, example added.

Comment: Typically, a small example is something anyone can paste into a Qt Creator project and compile. Yours is not a small example, it is an excerpt from a huge codebase with no attempt at any minimization.

Comment: You access the first `value` without checking if the `q.size()` is sufficient.

Comment: Hi Kuba Obet, I'm using visiual studio and it's difficult to prepare small(!) example with 3 difrrent projects which are shows the main problem, it must be expessed as theoritically examples like this. BTW checking size doesn't matter because I know what value come from there, problem is that, the query cannot executed properly in the XModule but in MainApp(exe) success. Looks sqldrivers or something else cannot load properly in XModule(dll one), db connection ok but query execution... All project outputs in same folder near the exe, in ../bin folder, also libmysql.dll in there too.